# How to get width and height of a view

Tags: java, android

I have a class called game that extends View that is added to a LinearLayout. I know that it is displaying my View but i need to get the width and height of the view in order to draw some of my images. Here is my constructor code:

```
public Game(Activity activ)
{
    activ.setContentView(R.layout.game);

    ...

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    setLayoutParams(lp);

    layout = (LinearLayout)activ.findViewById(R.id.game_layout);
    layout.addView(this);

    ...
}
```

now when i do this.getWidth() and this.getHeight() i keep getting a return value of 0. How can i get the width and the height of my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question today. Try that. It should work.

[Android - getting the width of a button which is set to wrap_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776042/android-getting-the-width-of-a-button-which-is-set-to-wrap-content/7776052#7776052)

Comment: oh my gosh thank you! Finally! I was getting sooo frustrated. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layout.getLayoutParams()` to get the layout param, and then use the `height` attribute in it.

UPDATE: If you are getting zero value, it could also mean that the view has not been initialized yet.

Comment: when do you recommend checking the width and height?

Comment: Can you also try layout.getMeasuredWidth() ?

Answer (score 0):

The View class has both a getHeight() and getWidth method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth()

Here's a blog on the subject as well:

http://syedrakibalhasan.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-width-and-height-dimensions.html