# How to get coordinates,height,width of a view or LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view child which is added to a LinearLayout on my main Layout. I want to get the coordinates of this view on screen and I use `getLocationOnWindow()`, `getHeight()`, and `getWidth()` methods but all the times I get 0.  Finally I found the reason.  Wherever I call these methods is during `onCreate()` method.  I mean, always I called before all layouts, view... etc. had been laid out. But I don't know When should I call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776042/android-getting-the-width-of-a-button-which-is-set-to-wrap-content/7776052#7776052

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are saying but have you called `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)` before trying `View myView = (View) findViewById(R.id.idofview)`